# where to find Jasperreport 's specific packages?

Tags: jasper-reports

friend ,where can I find  jasperreport's package
**net.sf.jasperreports.jdbc.concurrency**?

I now use jasperreports-4.0.0.jar, but there not exit this package. In which version can I find the package? thanks first :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following directories contain all the JAR files used by iReport and JasperReports:

```
$IREPORT_HOME/ireport/modules/ext
$IREPORT_HOME/ide10/modules/ext
```

Where `$IREPORT_HOME` is the installation directory for iReport.

Use http://www.findjar.com/ to find JAR files containing specific classes.

If you have to find a specific package, I would guess that the CLASSPATH is either not being set properly or there is a conflicting JAR file somewhere.

Without knowing why you want to find a specific package, it is difficult to answer the question.

Comment: thanks you, friend:) Cause I am interested in java parallel programming, and I can sure there exist this package in Jasper, since  I once read this package from a JASPER tutoriaL. But in my working version ,jasperreports-4.0.0.jar, there can not find the package.